# Selected file being removed from input when browse window cancelled

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

I've built a few different HTML forms that allow users to attach files via `<input type='file' />`, but I just noticed what seems to be a default Chrome behavior that I'd like to avoid - basically, if a user has attached a file but then clicks the 'Choose File' button again (either by accident or thinking they might want to change the file), hitting 'Cancel' removes the original file attachment.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior when using Chrome? If a user has already attached a file but then clicks the choose button again, cancelling should just close the browse window but leave the original file attached. I found that this does not happen with Safari, Firefox, or IE.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17889423/hitting-cancel-during-file-upload-in-chrome-clears-value

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Seems like this may just be a fact of life...